# Emoji inserted into MySQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, utf-8, emoji

I tried to add an emoji in chat box [textarea with emoji image input](http://onesignal.github.io/emoji-picker/demo/) but during the insertion time, i tried to var-dump the data, and that showed as below:

> ❤️❤️❤️❤️

I did not select any emojiis and inserted into the database

> ❤️❤️❤️????????❤️

like these, and I also did these steps

> 1)  ALTER DATABASE  CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
>
> 2)  ALTER TABLE  CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
>
> 3) ALTER TABLE  MODIFY  VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
>
> "thanks for @Timo Huovinen"

Any ways,I want to insert the emoji in database correctly, and after the insertion, the original emoji image should be listed.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I'm still stuck at how you got those emoji into your question +1

Comment: @Tim that emoji is :ok_hand: these codes .. any idea to show the result

Comment: See also "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0):

Parse the emojis as unicode characters before you insert them into your database, after that whenever you retrieve the emoji, just parse them back again.

Here's some info on that:
http://crocodillon.com/blog/parsing-emoji-unicode-in-javascript